# TortoiseSvn Folders Can't Commit

Tags: tortoisesvn, directory

Good morning,

I've got an ASP.NET MVC VB2008 .NET 3.5 project I'm upgrading to ASP.NET MVC3 VB2010 .NET 4.0 and it seems to be going OK so far.

I have got it into a working state and all the tests run correctly so it is ready to commit to subversion.

The problem is that to get the tests to update for .NET 4.0 I had to put the classes in a different folder, delete the project and recreate the project in the same place then put the classes back into it.

Now TortoiseSvn can't commit the folders as it already has copies of those folders, even though if I take them out and update the project they're not put back into the project.

Is there any way I can get tortoisesvn to overwrite the old files even though they are technically new files?

Regards,
Harry

Comment: HI when you copy the files into other folder than after doing that delete .svn files. Than create new project and copy the files into the newly created project and commit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably lost the hidden ".svn" folders used to keep track of changes.

Tortoise has an "export" feature. Right-click-and-drag the top level of you modified project to a safe place, choose "Export all here" from the menu.

The check your project out again to a new location, and drop the exported copy on top of it.
Delete any files/folder that shouldn't be there using Tortoise's "Delete" right-click menu item.

It should then be OK to check in, then clean up the mess we've made! :)

Comment: You sir are a gentleman and a scholar. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as yours. What I did was:

1. delete the old folder that you have for the project
2. create a new folder and redo "SVN Checkout"

Then you will have the standard menu back to your SVN.